# Re-Ordenar array de objetos según parámetro especifico

Tags: javascript, array, typescript

necesito reordenar un array segun el parametro especificado. por ejemplo:

```
let week = [{
 day: 'Lunes',
 value: 1
},
{
 day: 'Martes',
 value: 2
},
{
 day: 'Miercoles',
 value: 3
},
{
 day: 'Jueves',
 value: 4
},
{
 day: 'Viernes',
 value: 5
}]
```

ahora se necesita re-ordenarlo según parámetro por ejemplo 3 y se tomara el key "value". Debería quedar asi:

```
[{
 day: 'Miercoles',
 value: 3
},
{
 day: 'Jueves',
 value: 4
},
{
 day: 'Viernes',
 value: 5
}
{
 day: 'Lunes',
 value: 1
},
{
 day: 'Martes',
 value: 2
}]
```

Comment: Que tienes hecho hasta ahora?

Comment: tengo la función que recibe el parámetro por el cual se va a ordenar el array, y retornara el array re-ordenado. Intente con array.sort((a,b) => { return }) pero no me da el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer es lo que se llaman operaciones RoR y RoL (Rotate Right y Rotate Left, rotar a la derecha y rotar a la izquierda). En el ejemplo estás rotando a la izquierda tres posiciones, ya que mueves todos los elementos a una posición *menor* y el primero lo pones el último tres veces. Por suerte la clase Array de Javascript tiene los métodos necesarios para hacer esto de manera sencilla:

```js
let array=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function rotateLeft(array, times) {
  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    array.push(array.shift());
  }
}

function rotateRight(array, times) {
  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    array.unshift(array.pop());
  }
}
console.log(array.toString());
rotateLeft(array,3);
console.log(array.toString());
rotateRight(array,5);
console.log(array.toString());
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Pensando que siempre tendrás un array ordenado siendo este el caso que `value` va desde el `1...5` puedes hace lo siguiente:

```js
let week = [{
  day: 'Lunes',
  value: 1
  },
  {
  day: 'Martes',
  value: 2
  },
  {
  day: 'Miercoles',
  value: 3
  },
  {
  day: 'Jueves',
  value: 4
  },
  {
  day: 'Viernes',
  value: 5
}];
   
let order = function(number) {
    let before = [];
    let after = [];
    week.forEach((day) => {
        if (day.value >= number) {
            before.push(day);
            return;
        }
        after.push(day);
    });
    return before.concat(after);
}
console.log(order(3));
```

Donde tienes dos nuevos arreglos uno que se quedará con las posiciones antes del número de la semana a pasar y el otro después. Finalmente concatenas los resultados.

Comment: Correcto, al iniciar siempre el array está ordenado. Gracias por la ayuda